# JWPlayer and Firefox - Video does not 'complete'

Tags: asp.net, firefox, webforms, jwplayer

I am having a problem with jwplayer that only appears to happen in Firefox - in Chrome and IE everything works fine. This is on a ASP .Net web forms page. The video player is in a user control, sitting on the page.

1) When the video plays, and gets to the end, it stops playing, but doesn't actually complete. The .onComplete event never fires. If i fiddle around with reloading the page and clicking play I can get it to fire. But not consistently.

Here is my code:

```
jwplayer("myElement").setup({
        file: '<%= VideoUrl %>',
        image: '<%=ThumbnailImageUrl %>',
        width: "100%",
        aspectratio: "16:9",
        primary: thePrimary
    });

jwplayer("myElement").onReady(function () {
        jwplayer("myElement").onPlay(function () {
            var obj = this; //save a reference to 'this' jw object for reference in the setInterval callback.
            if (init_play == false) {
                init_play = true;
                if (trackingEnabled == 'True') {
                    this.seek(start);
                    init_play = true;
                    logVideoEvent(7, $('#<%=VideoIDHidden.ClientID %>').val(), 6, $('#PersonID').val(), $('#ContentPageID').val());
                } else {
                    init_play = true;
                }
            }
            if (!obj.playBegan) { //we only want this to trigger once when play begins (not on seek or ffd)
                obj.playBegan = true;
                HideValidationErrors();
                obj.durationProcessor = setInterval(function () {
                    if (obj.getDuration() !== -1) { //sometimes the movie duration isn't immediately available.
                        clearTimeout(obj.durationProcessor);
                        var filepath = jwplayer("myElement").getPlaylistItem()['file'];
                        var mycounter = 0;
                        obj.onTime(function (event) {
                            mycounter++;
                            if (mycounter == 10) {
                                if (trackingEnabled == 'True') {
                                    updateVideoProgress($('#<%=PersonVideoProgressID.ClientID %>').val(), $('#PersonCourseRelationshipID').val(), $('#ContentPageID').val(), $('#<%=VideoIDHidden.ClientID %>').val(), event.position, event.duration);
                                }
                                mycounter = 0;
                            }
                        });

                    }
                }, 0); //look for a duration every .25 seconds

            }
        });
        jwplayer("myElement").onComplete(function () {
            if (trackingEnabled == 'True') {
                if ($('#<%=WelcomeStepHidden.ClientID %>').val() == '4') {
                    updateWelcomeProgress($('#<%=PersonWelcomeProgressID.ClientID %>').val(), $('#PersonCourseGroupRelationshipID').val(), 4, true);
                }
                if ($('#<%=WelcomeStepHidden.ClientID %>').val() == '1') {
                    updateWelcomeProgress($('#<%=PersonWelcomeProgressID.ClientID %>').val(), $('#PersonCourseGroupRelationshipID').val(), 1, false);
                }
                logVideoEvent(13, $('#<%=VideoIDHidden.ClientID %>').val(), 6, $('#PersonID').val(), $('#ContentPageID').val());
            }
        });
        $("a[title='" + urlsegment + "']").click();
    });
```

2) Maybe related? Autoplay does not seem to work in Firefox. The loading icon appears, but just spins. I have to manually pause and click play again to get it to play. Sometimes, when I do this, its starts playing, but the loading icon never disappears. If I go to the JWPlayer website and play their sample video, it seems to work fine.

Comment: Can you provide a link?

Comment: Unfortunately, its behind a password.

Comment: Could you put up a non password protected page?

Comment: OK, Ethan, I made a simple video page. You should see all the problems I described. I'm console logging in a couple of places, in particular, the 'onCompleted'. Again, this only seems toi happen in Firefox.   https://nemours.mypumpchoice.org/VideoTester.aspx

Comment: The onComplete() event works for me in FF. See attached. http://i.imgur.com/LSgLfdY.jpg

Comment: Yes. I see that I am using the Developer Edition of firefox. In regular firefox it works. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, any time.